# Warning in the console about permission denied (Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code:

```
var handler:FIRDatabaseHandle!
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.handler = self.ref.observe(.value, with: {[weak self] (snapshot) in
        var _tasks = Array<Task>()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let task = Task(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            _tasks.append(task)
        }

        self?.tasks = _tasks
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

So when I leave this controller (actually I sign out) I see next warning in the console:

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB04822] Listener at
>   /users/ovLWTmGIPFaF6DaLzrPBBr13/tasks failed: permission_denied

Comment: I got same warning when I missed  in hurry  
let reff = ref.child("activeList").

 I have directly queried by   :- 
 ref = Database.database().reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "parent").queryEqual(toValue: projectRef)   //permission denied

So I have replace by  Database.database().reference().child("activeList").queryOrdered(byChild: "parent").queryEqual(toValue: projectRef)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means that the listener is attached to a location where it doesn't have permission.

You can also safely ignore the logging, since you're not likely to care about the data anymore.

But if you prefer a clean log: to prevent the logging make sure that you unregister your observers **before** signing out. To do this, call [`removeObserver(withHandle:...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeobserverwithhandle) or (maybe easier in this case) [`removeAllObservers`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeallobservers).

Comment: This is true, I read that best practice is to remove observer in viewDidDisappear but actually it invoke warning. Should I better call removeAllObservers right before FIRAuth.auth().signout?

Comment: @frank how do i check for permission denied in swift so that I can display an appropriate error message to the user!?

Answer (score 20):

It happens because you are not authorized to the Database.
You have a listener attached to a location where it doesn't have permission.

Check the Rules Tab in the Realtime database

If it's

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write":"auth != null"
  }
}
```

This means that only authorized user's can write and read the Data.

Changing to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```

Allows anyone to read/write the Database.
Of course it is (usually) not a valid rule for a production environment but it is useful to check your issue.

Comment: But I do not ask for any data why do I have permission denied when I leave to the login screen? There is no data from database.

Comment: But you have a listener to a ref.

Comment: Changing the rules to ".read": true, ".write":true worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please lookup image and follow these steps. If you are beginner and facing problem in image. I make little video about error.

**Video Solution :** 
https://youtu.be/fZrOkCqQpTc

**Image Solution :**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was in the wrong tab of the database rules view. At the top, to the right of "Database", it should say "Realtime database", not "Cloud Firestore".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Realtime Database Rules are restricted to authenticated users by default.

```
 ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"
```

If you haven't changed the rules, or aren't authenticated you won't be able to read or write anything from your database. For now, if you're just trying things out you can try setting the "auth != null" to true, which will allow anyone to write to and read from the database.

```
".read": true,
".write": true
```

This is generally not recommended since it's not secure. There should be a tab next to data where you can adjust the rules.

You can read up on the Database Rules in the link I provided below.

[Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)